# How to fetch metrics such as likes, views, impressions, etc for a linkedin post using an api?

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm trying to retrieve metrics for a LinkedIn post using an API. I've created an app on Linkedin Developer, but I'm not sure which product would be best suited for this task. Can you help point me in the right direction? Thank you!